# Is there a way to change date value (in the field above all the cells) to look like in a formatted cell?

Tags: vba, date, format

I have a set of data where date format needs to be changed into "dd/mmm/yyyy". I have done this in the spreadsheet, however when you click on a cell the value field that shows true value is in different format (m/dd/yyyy). Because this file is being loaded into another system I need that "true" value to look exactly as the formatted cell.

Few things I tried:

```
pmtSummary.Range("A" & pmtlastrow).Value = DateValue(Format(Date, "dd/mmm/yyyy"))
pmtSummary.Range("A" & pmtlastrow).Value = Format(Date, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
pmtSummary.Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mmm/yyyy"
pmtSummary.Range("A" & pmtlastrow).Value = dataSh.Range("A" & I).Value2
pmtSummary.Range("A" & pmtlastrow).Value = dataSh.Range("A" & I).Text
```

All I need is value field to reflect what is exactly in the cell. Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure it is, as far as I'm aware the excel edit field will show the system default date format, which can only be changed in your windows/computer settings.

Comment: A cell formatted as text will retain that format ***if*** the cell is formatted before the value is entered.  The bigger question, is how your data gets into Excel.  If you're importing it from another an external file the you should be using the import data feature on the data tax.